# What is known about the Original Ramayana?

Tags: ramayana, valmiki

In a comment, a user says:

[Is this event present in itihasapuranas or other canonical Sanskrit scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/51397/is-this-event-present-in-itihasapuranas-or-other-canonical-sanskrit-scriptures#comment159719_51397)

> Ramayana is *shatha-koti-pravistara* (100 crore shlokas) of which only 24K are available on the *bhuloka*.

This user claims the original Ramayana contains 100 crore shlokas. Does this true original also contain 6 or 7 Kāṇḍas like the one available to us on the Bhūloka? Is Uttara-Kāṇḍa also a part of it?

Comment: It is however known there are more than 100 crore ramayan

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The original Rāmāyaṇa by Mahaṛṣi Vālmīki is indeed said to be *śatakoṭi-pravistaram‌* i.e., extending to a 100 crore *ślokas*.

This is stated in the Matsya Mahā-Purāṇa

> #### [Chapter 53](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.45856/page/n186/mode/1up?view=theater), Matsya Purāṇa
>
> अष्टादश पुराणानि कृत्वा सत्यवतीसुतः ॥ भारताख्यानमखिलं चक्रे
> तदुपबृंहितम् ।    लक्षेणैकेन यत्प्रोक्तं वेदार्थपरिबृंहितम् ॥६९॥
> वाल्मीकिना तु यत्प्रोक्तं रामोपाख्यानमुत्तमम् ।
>  ब्रह्मणाभिहितं
> यच्च **शतकोटिप्रविस्तरम्** ॥७०॥ आहृत्य नारदायैवं तेन वाल्मीकये पुनः ।
> वाल्मीकिना च लोकेषु धर्मकामार्थसाधनम् ।  एवं सपादाः पञ्चैते लक्षा
> मत्ये प्रकोतिताः ॥७१॥
>
> > - 69, 70, 71. The great sage Vyasa, after compiling the 18 Purāṇas, indulged in the composition of the story of Mahābhārata, in order to
> >   magnify their bulk, which was an addition to the Purāṇas, by another
> >   lakhs of ślokas.  And in which he has condensed the sense of the
> >   Vedas. **The glorious story of Rāmāyaṇa, sung by the sage Vālmīki, at
> >   the instance of Brahmā, also extends to a hundred crore of ślokas.
> >   Brahmā narrated the original Rāmāyaṇa to Nārada Muni; the latter
> >   revealed it to Vālmīki, who gave it to the world, and which is a means
> >   of giving Dharma, Kāma, and Artha.** And hence, the total number of
> >   verses in all the *Purāṇas* and *Itihāsas*  is thus known to be
> >   525,000 in counting.”
>
> English Translation by B.D. Basu

<sup>Access the Sanskrit + Hindi translation by the Gita Press Gorakhpur [from here](https://archive.org/details/matsya-puran-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/n230/mode/1up?view=theater)</sup>

However, the Matsya Purāṇa does not answer any further queries in regards to the OP's questions ( viz. "*Does this true original also contain 6 or 7 *Kāṇḍas* like the one available to us on the Bhūloka? Is *Uttara-Kāṇḍa* also a part of it?*")

For these questions, we may gain some insight from the Ānanda Rāmāyaṇa

> #### [Sarga 8, Manohara Kāṇḍa](https://archive.org/details/HindiBookAnandRamayan/page/n671/mode/2up?view=theater), Ānanda Rāmāyaṇa,
>
> भारतं  त्विहासञ्च रामायणसमुद्भवम् । यद्वेद्पाठपुण्यं तज्ज्ञेयं
> रामायणस्य च ॥६0॥ पाठात्तदर्द श्रवणे व्याख्यातुश्च दशाधिकम् ।
> **वाल्मीकिना कृतं यत्र शतकोटिप्रविस्तरम्** ॥६१॥ तत्सर्वेषामादिभूतं
> महामंगलकारकम् । रामायणादेव नाना संति रामायणानि हि ॥६२॥ शेषभूतं
> चतुर्विशत्सहस्रं प्रथमं स्मृतम् । तथा च योगवासिष्ठमध्यात्माख्यं
> तथास्मृतम् ॥६३॥ वायुपुत्रकृतं चापि नारदोक्तं तथा पुनः । लघुरामायणं चैव
> वृहद्रामायण तथा ॥६४॥ अगस्त्युक्तं महाश्रेष्ठं साररामायणं तथा ।
> देहरामायणं चापि वृतरामायणं पुनः ॥६५॥ जमरामायणं रम्यं भारद्वाजं तथैव च
> । शिवरामायणं क्रौंच भारतस्य च जैमिनेः ॥६६॥ आत्मधर्म
> श्वेतकेतुॠषेश्श्चैव जटायुषः ॥६७॥ रवेः पुलस्तेदॆव्याश्च गुह्यकं मंगलं
> तथा । गाधिजं च सुतीक्ष्णं च सुग्रीवं च विभीषणम् ॥६८॥
> तथाऽऽनंदरामायणमेतन्मंगलकारकम् । एवं सहस्रशः संति श्रीरामचरितानि हि
> ॥६९। कः समर्थोऽस्ति तेषां हि संख्या वक्त सविस्तरात्॥ शतकोटिनितादेव
> विभक्तानि पृथक् पृथक् ॥७०॥
>
> > - The piety-merit gained from reading the *Vedas* and that reading the *Rāmāyaṇa* is equivalent. Reading the basic text gives half the merit while reading it with expositions gives merit ten times more.
>
> > - **The Orginal Rāmāyaṇa consisting of 100 crores *ślokas* composed by the sage Vālmīki is the primordial root of all the known/unknown
> >   *Rāmāyaṇas*, and is extremely auspicious.**
>
> > - **From a small part of the appendix-endings of that Original 100 crore *ślokas* Rāmāyaṇa, all the presently known Rāmāyaṇas are
> >   composed viz. the popular '24000 *ślokas* Vālmīki-Rāmāyaṇa', the
> >   'Yoga-Vāsiṣtha', 'Adhyātma-Rāmāyaṇa', 'the Rāmāyaṇa by Vāyūputra
> >   Hanumāna', 'Nārada-Rāmāyaṇa',** 'Laghu-Rāmāyaṇa', 'Brihad-Rāmāyaṇa',
> >   'Sage Agastya authored Sāra-Rāmāyaṇa', 'Deha-Rāmāyaṇa',
> >   'Vrata-Rāmāyaṇa', 'Bhārdvāja-Rāmāyaṇa', 'Śiva-Rāmāyaṇa',
> >   'Kraunca-Rāmāyaṇa', 'Bharata-Rāmāyaṇa', 'Jaimini-Rāmāyaṇa', and
> >   several other Rāmāyaṇas including the 'Rāmāyaṇa by Ātma-dharma', the
> >   Rāmāyaṇa by Jaṭāyu', the the Rāmāyaṇa by Śvetaketu ṛṣi, the Rāmāyaṇa
> >   by Pulastya ṛṣi, the Rāmāyaṇa by Devī, the Rāmāyaṇa by Viśvāmitra, the
> >   Rāmāyaṇa by Sutikṣṇa, the Rāmāyaṇa by Sugriva, the Rāmāyaṇa by
> >   Vibhīṣaṇa, and this meritorious Ānanda-Rāmāyaṇa.
>
> > - In this way thousands
> >   of Rāmāyaṇas have been composed which sings the glories of Rāma and
> >   his character.
>
> > - **There is none capable enough to elucidate on each and every Rāmāyaṇa. But know that, the Original Rāmāyaṇa which consists of 100
> >   crores of *ślokas* is the source of all these Rāmāyaṇas.**

---

### To Conclude:

- So, it is clear that the Original Rāmāyaṇa by Mahaṛṣi Vālmīki is the source of all the Rāmāyaṇas including the '24000 *ślokas* Vālmīki-Rāmāyaṇa'.
- The scriptural information about the division of this 'True Original Rāmāyaṇa' also containing 6 or 7 Kāṇḍas like the one available to us on the Bhūloka is not mentioned. We cannot comment on the structure of the Original, from the information available.